# SFTP connection successful but can't transfer large files

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, sftp

I'm using SFTP to transfer files between a server and a node. Session from server to node is fine, there is no permission or path issue either. And between the two devices I can put/get file of size 70Bytes without issues, but when I try larger files like 10-12 MBs, the transfer starts and immediately session is reset (closed) with error:

**sftp connection closed by remote host couldn't read packet**

When I check the node, a part of the file like around 10000 bytes gets copied within a second and then session is terminated. I tried the same using different files, and tried different nodes (clients) and same situation. These clients are some telecom devices. Any help/idea? I don't use SFTP much so not sure if I have to enable some switch or mode to make it work.

Comment: Is there a firewall between client and server? Are there any logs that you could ask your network admin to look at to see if the firewall is root cause?

Comment: it could be a firewall but, I will check. below is the log: 

"sftp> put TEST
Uploading TEST to /XYZ/TEST.txt
TEST.txt                                                                                                       2%  288KB 288.0KB/s   00:40 ETAConnection to 10.155.227.97 closed by remote host.
Couldn't send packet: Connection reset by peer"

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Optimize connection buffer size" in the
[Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection) :

[image]

You could also try `scp` as an alternative.

Comment: I cannot use any utility software, only CLI is available on the system. is there some option via CLI to do this?

Comment: See [Raw Site Settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings) as regarding `SendBuf`.